# Is Mashiach going to come in Nissan/Tishrei, or can he come at any time?

Tags: messiah, maseches-sanhedrin, maseches-rosh-hashana

The Gemara in Rosh HaShanah 10b-11a says:

> תניא רבי אליעזר אומר בתשרי נברא העולם בתשרי נולדו אבות בתשרי מתו אבות בפסח נולד יצחק בראש השנה נפקדה שרה רחל וחנה בראש השנה יצא יוסף מבית האסורין בר"ה בטלה עבודה מאבותינו במצרים בניסן נגאלו **בתשרי עתידין ליגאל** ר' יהושע אומר בניסן נברא העולם בניסן נולדו אבות בניסן מתו אבות בפסח נולד יצחק בר"ה נפקדה שרה רחל וחנה בר"ה יצא יוסף מבית האסורין בר"ה בטלה עבודה מאבותינו במצרים בניסן נגאלו **בניסן עתידין ליגאל**

Focusing on the boldfaced portions: According to R’ Eliezer, Mashiach will come in Tishrei; according to R’ Yehoshua, Mashiach will come in Nissan. It’s clear that this refers to the coming of Mashiach specifically from the explanation of R’ Eliezer’s opinion brought on 11b:

> בתשרי עתידין ליגאל אתיא שופר שופר כתיב הכא תקעו בחדש שופר וכתיב התם (ישעיהו כז, יג) ביום ההוא יתקע בשופר גדול
>
> In Tishrei we will be redeemed - he learns out a Gezeirah Shavah of “Shofar” “Shofar.” It says here [by Rosh HaShanah] “blow the Shofar in the month,” and it says there [regarding Mashiach], “and it will be on that day a great Shofar blast will be blown.”

Compare Sanhedrin 98a:

> אמר רבי אלכסנדרי רבי יהושע בן לוי רמי כתיב (ישעיהו ס, כב) בעתה וכתיב אחישנה זכו אחישנה לא זכו בעתה
>
> Says R’ Alexandri: R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi poses a contradiction. It says [regarding the coming of Mashiach] “in its time” and it [immediately] says “I will hasten it.” [Is it in its time, or is it hastened to come early?] If they merit, “I will hasten it.” If they don’t merit, [Mashiach will still come] “in its time.”

Considering this latter Gemara, is the former intended to be understood as a prediction of when he is *actually* going to come, and R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi refers to the *year* of Mashiach (or just flat-out argues on R’ Eliezer and R’ Yehoshua), or are R’ Eliezer and R’ Yehoshua predicting Mashiach’s “time,” which R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi says isn’t necessarily when he *will* come?

Comment: "הלכות מלכים יב:ב "וכל אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן לא ידע אדם איך יהיו עד שיהיו

Comment: To continue Alex - Acc to Rambam the Moshiach does lots of things before we realize he IS the Moshiach, therefore the "coming" is questionable in the first place.

Comment: @Alex He’s just paskening R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi. My question is if R’ Eliezer and R’ Yehoshua are necessarily in conflict, or if R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi needs to be reinterpreted, or if their opinions do work together. I don’t see how that Rambam changes anything.

Comment: cc @AlBerko ^^^

Comment: R' Eliezer and R' Yehoshua could be discussing when בעתה is, with R' Yehoshua B. Levi saying but if we merit, he could come any time. That oversimplifies things because both R' Eliezer and R' Yehoshua have additional opinions on these matters, but a first impression harmonization.

Comment: @Yishai How is that different than my second suggestion?

Comment: @DonielF, it may not be, I wasn't sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: אחכה לו **בכל יום** from the 13 principals of faith

Comment: @Negel That just adds to the question. It doesn't answer it. Even with that, the Gemara in RH still stands. Also, in the Rambam's original words, he doesn't say בכל יום. His wording is היסוד שנים עשר 
ימות המשיח והוא להאמין ולאמת שיבא ולא יחשב שיתאחר אם יתמהמה חכה לו ולא ישים לו זמן ולא יעשה.